# Solving $\lim \limits_{x \to 2}{\frac{\sqrt{6-x}-2}{\sqrt{3-x}-1}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I'm trying to solve the following limit.

---

### $$\lim \limits_{x \to 2}{\frac{\sqrt{6-x}-2}{\sqrt{3-x}-1}}$$

---

Unfortunately, I haven't made any headway.

I tried multiplying by the conjugates of both the numerator and denominator (in 2 different attempts, of course), but ended up with a monster of an expression either time.

Comment: @Mattos -- I did; and I got a monster of an expression. :)

Comment: Can you use L'Hospital's rule? If so its easy

Comment: @R_D -- No, not yet. I'm going through a calculus textbook, but so far I've only learnt about limits (pretty much as advanced as The Squeeze Theorem).

Comment: @SirJony Sorry, I probably should have read your question in its entirety.

Comment: Multiplying with conjugates won't help you because after multiplying with conjugates you get the same indeterminate form $$\frac{0}{0}$$

Comment: Duplicate: [$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to2} {\sqrt{6-x}-2\over\sqrt{3-x}-1}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/195532/201168). (*Found using [Approach0.xyz](https://approach0.xyz/)*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $y = 3 - x$. Then we have 
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{\sqrt{6-x} - 2}{\sqrt{3 - x} - 1}
&= \lim_{y \to 1} \frac{\sqrt{y + 3} - 2}{\sqrt{y} - 1}\\
&= \lim_{y \to 1} \frac{(y + 3 - 2^2)(\sqrt{y} + 1)}{(y - 1)(\sqrt{y + 3} + 2)}\\
&= \lim_{y \to 1} \frac{(y - 1)(\sqrt{y} + 1)}{(y-1)(\sqrt{y + 3} + 2)}\\
&= \lim_{y \to 1} \frac{\sqrt{y} + 1}{\sqrt{y + 3} + 2} = \frac{1 + 1}{2 + 2} = \frac{1}{2}
\end{align}

Comment: @SirJony I multiplied by the conjugate. Sorry I skipped a bit of simplication. Similar to $\frac{a - b}{c - d} = \frac{(a - b)(a+b)(c+d)}{(c-d)(a+b)(c+d)} = \frac{(a^2 - b^2)(c+d)}{(c^2 - d^2)(a+b)}$.

Comment: Oh, I see. Also, how'd you figure this out!? I would've never thought of this.

Comment: @SirJony When solving problems try to see if a substitution can make the problem simpler. Radicals are normally a pain, so you want to reduce the amount of terms inside them. Recognizing when to use a substitution comes with experience. Soon enough you will be able to solve problems like these in no time!

Answer (score 1):

You can apply L'Hospital Rule because after putting limit, we get,
$$\frac{0}{0}$$
Applying L'Hospital Rule,
$$\lim_{x\to2}\frac{\frac{-1}{2\sqrt{6-x}}}{\frac{-1}{2\sqrt{3-x}}}$$
After simplifying, you get,
$$\lim_{x\to2}\frac{\sqrt{3-x}}{\sqrt{6-x}}$$
Applying limits,
$$\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$\lim_{x\to2}\dfrac{\sqrt{6-x}-2}{\sqrt{3-x}-1}=\lim_{x\to2}\dfrac{6-x-2^2}{3-x-1^2}\cdot\lim_{x\to2}\dfrac{\sqrt{3-x}+1}{\sqrt{6-x}+2}$$

Answer (score 0):

I like to let
my variables approach zero.
So I would do this
like this:

$\begin{array}\\
\lim \limits_{x \to 2}\dfrac{\sqrt{6-x}-2}{\sqrt{3-x}-1}
&=\lim \limits_{y \to 0}\dfrac{\sqrt{6-(y+2)}-2}{\sqrt{3-(y+2)}-1}
\qquad(x = y+2)\\
&=\lim \limits_{y \to 0}\dfrac{\sqrt{4-y}-2}{\sqrt{1-y}-1}\\
&=\lim \limits_{y \to 0}\dfrac{2\sqrt{1-y/4}-2}{\sqrt{1-y}-1}\\
&=\lim \limits_{y \to 0}\dfrac{2(1-y/8+O(y^2))-2}{(1-y/2+O(y^2))-1}\\
&=\lim \limits_{y \to 0}\dfrac{-y/4+O(y^2)}{-y/2+O(y^2)}\\
&=\lim \limits_{y \to 0}\dfrac{-1/4+O(y)}{-1/2+O(y)}\\
&=\dfrac12\\
\end{array}
$